# NVDA Mainframe Accessibility Testing

Tags: accessibility, mainframe, nvda

I am working on mainframe accessibility testing using NVDA however tool is not reading any of the field when i pressses tab key, screen reader is remains silent.

Mainframe software : attachmate extra xtreme 9.4
any suggestion much helpful becasue I could not find much infromation from internet. does any python script for NVDA mainframe accessibility

Comment: Try running NVDA with admin rights if the other software runs with admin rights (shows a Windows UAC prompt at startup).

Comment: @DaveS How do I run nvda as an admin mode ?

Comment: Right-click on the NVDA icon instead of left-click, choose Run As Administrator.  If that works, you might suggest to them that they offer a version that requires a UAC prompt / runs as admin even when you left-click it

Comment: @DaveS I have tried to run as admin but screen reader still is not reading anything when I press Tab key. any other alternate solution please suggest.

Comment: That's the only general-purpose fix I know about.   Have you tried here? - https://www.nvaccess.org/get-help/